# How can I "untruncate" series data with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some time series data that's effectively been recorded at a truncated precision relative to the rate it changes.  This leads to a stairstep-like quality when I graph it.  I'm using Pandas to manipulate and store the data.  Is there a way I can use Pandas to smooth out the stairsteps, inferring extra precision from the time series data?

In more detail, here's a sample graph:

[image: sample graph showing stairstep data]

The green line represents recorded temperatures.  My temperature sensor is only accurate to a tenth of a degree Celsius, but the rate of temperature change is significantly less than a tenth of a degree every recording interval.

I think it should be possible to infer extra precision based on how quickly the values are changing, but I'm not sure what the best way to do that is.  I got an okay-ish looking result by using `pandas.rolling_mean`, but that uses a fixed window for the mean, even though different parts of the graph would benefit from different window sizes.  It also shortens narrower peaks because of the relatively-wide window.

[image]

Ideally I'd like to get something continuous enough that I can take a derivative of the data and not have tremendously spiky results.

So what, if anything, in Pandas can help me get the results I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you post example data?

Comment: Sure.  The temperature dataset for the above graphs is here: https://pastebin.com/js9Pv5ge .  The first column is the index (elapsed seconds) and the second column is the temperature reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's what I've done so far.  I get okay results from this, though I still think there should be something that feels less like a hack.

If we assume that the temperature sensor is reasonably accurate to a hundredth of a degree but is only reporting tenths of a degree, we can infer that when a reading changes from, say 0.1 to 0.2 the actual reading at that time is around 0.15.  So I scan through the series, find all of the places where the value changes, set the value to the mean of the two, and set all other values to NaN.  Then I use `Series.interpolate` to construct pleasant-looking curves that are, for the most part, at least as accurate as the original readings.

Here's the code:

```
def smooth_data(data, method='linear'):
    data = data.copy().astype(np.float64)
    for i0, i1 in zip(data.index[1:], data.index[2:]):
        if data[i0] == data[i2]:
            data[i0] = np.nan
        else:
            data[i0] = (data[i0] + data[i1]) / 2
    return data.interpolate(method)
```

Here's what the same data looks like with this smoothing (and cubic interpolation):

[image: graph with smoothed curves]